# Arduino Web server response is "It Works!"

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, intel-galileo

I am quite new to Arduino so maybe this is a simple problem, but I have not been able to find a solution.

I have a Intel Galileo Gen. 2 board. I am trying to write a simple program that offers a web server where, upon request, It returns the value obtained from a sensor (any text would do for my problem). I have succesfully configured the network and obtained the value but every request to the server gets a "It works!" message as a response. I have tried with different browsers (from chromw to lynx) and different nework locations.

This is the code I am using:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x98, 0x4F, 0xEE, 0x05, 0x65, 0x02 };
char SENSORNAME[ ] = "galileo01";
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 15, 177);
IPAddress dnServer(8, 8, 8, 8);

EthernetServer server(80);

int sensorPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int readValue = 0;
int prevValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  system("ifconfig enp0s20f6 down ");
  system("ip link set enp0s20f6 name eth0");
  system("ifconfig eth0 up");
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dnServer);
  server.begin();

}

void loop() {
  readValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println("Connection: close");
          client.println();
          client.print("{\"sensor\":\"");
          client.print(SENSORNAME);
          client.print( "\",\"value\":\"");
          client.print(readValue);
          client.println("\"}");
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } 
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

What I see is that when making the request the loop() function is not handling it. I can see the sensor reading results, but it never goes through the if clause:

```
 EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
```

Is there any internal web server? How do I set it off?

Comment: Are you sure you whether you have flashed this code into Arduino?

Comment: I belive so. I have set some traces in the code and I can see my messages in the serial monitor. Also, I see that the IP is correctly set, as it is answering the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found it. Default system comes with a running web server that was not allowing to set a new server on port 80. Adding this code has solved the isue:

```
system("systemctl stop lighttpd > /dev/ttyGS0");
system("systemctl stop disable > /dev/ttyGS0");
```